# Prevent bootstrap 3 modal when form submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">     
 //something here
 <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>  
</form>
```

My modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When form is submitted the form closes, similar problems are mentioned on stackO, but no working solutions.

Comment: Even after fixing obvious typos it seems not clear to me what you are asking for.

Comment: What you actually asking for ?

Comment: Modual closes after form is submited, and how to fix this?

Comment: Would you provide full code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this has been answered before, the relevant topics explaining you should add `data-backdrop="static"` to your code.  Like so:

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unless there's something going on here you haven't explained.

Comment: modual still closes when i push the submit.